# how to set click event on parent using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Following is the HTML structure I'm using

```
<div id="divid">
   <table>
     <tr>
       <td onclick="var ele = document.getElementById('inputID'); ele.click();">
          <input id="inputID" onclick="event.stopPropagation();"  name="nameOfElement" type="checkbox"/>
       </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I'm trying to set a click event on  element using JQuery as follows:( for other functionality elsewhere in page)

```
 $("#inputID").parent().on('click',function(){ // call to other functions})
```

this attachment leads to following error:

```
  Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: )
```

I have to give following functionality:

1. If user click on td then input element must be checked and if clicked on  then click event must not be propagated to parent i.e. td as that will reverse the effect.
2. Also I want to Jquery's click event to execute.

Currently, only first functionality is working and event.stopPropagation() is stoping the second one.

how can I achieve both of them?

please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/zqg0Lgbh/4/ for demo of issue.

Comment: I don't understand the question. And it's been a very long time since `live` deprecation (and removal).

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/live/ live() is long deprecated, check for yourself

Comment: okay I will replace it with On()

Comment: @dystroy I edited Question and include a demo on fiddle, have a look now

Comment: @ArvindBishnoi What's not working right in your demo ?

Comment: @dystroy When you click on radio button ( row 1,column 1, under 3) the div below the table must hide. That is not happening due to event.stopPropagation() given in inline ( for Fulfilling First functionality)

Comment: @ArvindBishnoi OK, got it (see answer). It's a good question but your approach with propagation of click wasn't the right one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would remove all those ugly inline event handlers.

Then, I would use jQuery to ensure a click on a cell containing a radio button checks that radio button :

```
$('td:has(>input[type=radio])').click(function(){
   $('input[type=radio]', this).prop('checked', true);
});
```

This way you don't have to use `stopPropagation`.

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/9u7jmctd/) (note that I fixed a few other things, like using fixing the missing name in the function declaration or importing jQuery.

Asides:

- you really should stop using inline styles and inline event handlers. This code isn't maintainable.
- changing the behavior of widgets and their surroundings isn't really a best practice as it surprises the user and leads to various ergonomics problem

Comment: i totally agree with you, but this decision is not mine. That Inline code is legacy I got and no one is willing change approach.

Comment: Then just remove all those event handlers just before your code : `$('.Pointer').each(function(){ this.onclick=null });`

Answer (score 3):

Use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of live() since live() is long [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

```
$("#inputID").parent().on('click',function(){
```

Also, it's not a good idea to use

```
<td onclick="var ele = document.getElementById('inputID'); ele.click();"
```

Instead create on click event in JS like shown above. (and add class or id to your td element so you can attacht click event to it ofcourse). If you must call onclick from HTML, then perhaps try

```
onclick="javascript:var ele = document.getElementById('inputID'); ele.click();"
```

That sometimes helps if you are not sure the code is being executed. Also try to alert() something to make sure the code actually executes.

Also you have a syntax error in your code. (onlcick instead of onclick)

```
<input id="inputID" onlcick="event.stopPropagation();"
```

Comment: Call to click event never comes!

Comment: that Jquery click event which I'm attaching to parent of input element for controlling show/hide other elements in page.

Comment: I did tried to put alert() there but I got error (please look in question Itself).

Comment: The event that you add to parent inline, or the one that is added in JS?

Comment: Can anyone tell me from where that extra ")" comes into picture??

Comment: one in the JS. parent inline is working as expected.

Comment: Maybe you forgot the ";" after the ")" ? I know it's not mandatory, but you can try. Also, I hope in your code you don't have that closing "})" commented as in your question above?

Answer (score 0):

Remove inline handler

```
$("#inputID").click(function () {

    if (this.checked) {
        alert("call other function")
    }

});
```

Comment: If I remove inline handler then what about First functionality. Also Call to click event never comes!

Comment: why you call click event  , you can call this other function inside this checked

Comment: I have to some show/hide thing elsewhere in page which depends upon this answer.

Comment: Then you can use your function depends on this.checked

Comment: I'm not able to follow, can you please elaborate?

Comment: No I need to show another section upon check and hide when unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$("#inputID").parent().on("click", function(){
    alert("Trigger other events");
});
```

Here's a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/vkewuu6L/

If you look at the fiddle the border represents the parent of "#inputID". You can click on the border to trigger the alert.